# Deployment of ARM template to Devops branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment, azure-bicep

As a part of learning bicep, I've created an arm template for linked service to an existing ADF. When I deploy the template from ADF, It is being deployed directly in live mode.

Would it be possible to deploy that template and have those newly created Linked Service to appear in a branch of my devops repository? So that I can have those in repository?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying ARM to a new data factory, it is automatically deployed in live mode.

If you published a new linked service from data factory, it will appear the next time you deploy.

If you want more flexibility in deploying data factory, take a took at [SQLPlayer](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools). A library for flexible data factory deployment.

Comment: The ARMtemplate is for creating new linked services to an _existing_ data factory where I already have the _repository integration_. **And, its not about deployment**, I want those linked service's json to be there in one branch of repo.